# Python/What kind of sort is this one..?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am very new to computer programming, and I was trying to practice the insert-sort algorithm by writing the code. I have coded the python code below, but I am not sure I did the *insert-sort*. Is this the logic of insert sort? if not, what kind of algorithm is this?

```
import random

data = random.sample(range(100), 10)
print(data)
temp = int()
for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    for index in range(i + 1, len(data)):
        if data[i] > data[index]:
            temp = data[i]
            data[i] = data[index]
            data[index] = temp

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is an example of bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

It's bubble sort. You can find more info here: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort